# Open split window at far left

Tags: vim-windows

I use `:vs` to open a window. If I want this window to be the leftmost window, no matter what the currently active window is, how can I do it?

Comment: You cannot really change the behavior of `:vs` to do what you want. I myself just do `<C-w>v<C-w>H`. But more single-minded way would be `:vert topleft split`

Comment: @klaus This is an answer, please turn it into one. You can use `:topleft :vsplit`, no need to switch to `:vert`. Also `<C-w>H` on its own after `:vs`, no need to switch to `<C-w>v` for that to work either. But it's still an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: @filbranden, thanks. I posted an answer, including your suggestions. I actually didn't know `:topleft` was a `{cmd}` modifier, maybe cause it is only and specifically useful for splitting windows; and I personally do that with keybindings, not commands. That's why I suggested `<C-w>v` instead of `:vs`: it wasn't an answer and I was talking about my personal workflow. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions, and please, if you have time, check if the answer is correct.

Comment: @klaus Yes it was good. I edited it to remove the references to `:vert` (that's not really relevant here), rephrased it a little bit and added links to the help pages. Let me know if you disagree with any of the edits. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a couple of methods to achieve the same end result as  your request.

- You can just open a vertical split and then move it to leftmost position using <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> (note that the "h" is uppercase.) See [`:help CTRL-W_H`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_H) for more information.
- You can use [`:topleft`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Atopleft) to modify your `:vs` command to open the window in the leftmost position. You can use the following command for that:

  ```
  :topleft vs
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is for the far right, but same idea.

```
function! CloseVspIfNeed()
    "let x = tabpagebuflist()
    "if len(x)==1
    "vsp
    "endif
    for k in getwininfo()
        if k['winrow']<=2 && k['wincol']>1
            "look no further
            let id=k['winid']
            call win_gotoid(id)
            :close
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

You might want to do :

```
set splitright
call CloseVspIfNeed()
vnew
```

to replace the window at the far right with new one.